# Javascript getting terminated on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm trying to do a server method call from the client side for 2 days in a row. Gone through many blogs and posts. I'm new to jquery and hence relied on the online demo all the way through. The problem i'm facing right now is my jquery will get initiated on call and gets terminated on a function call used within that. Can i get some help out here. Sample Code is appended herewith. You can find this code in the following link too http://aspdotnetcode.source-of-humor.com/Articles/JQuery/JqueryAjaxRequestForCallingASPNetServerSideFunction.aspx. Any help would be appreciated.

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="JqueryAjaxRequestSample.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function InitiateJqueryAjaxRequestCall() {

    var reqParameter1 = $('#<%= txtParameter1.ClientID %>')[0].value;
    var reqParameter2 = $('#<%= txtParameter2.ClientID %>')[0].value;

    var requestParameters = '{' +
                            'reqParameter1:"' + reqParameter1 + '", ' +
                            'reqParameter2:"' + reqParameter2 + '"' +
                            '}';

    // Configure AJAX call to server                        
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "JqueryAjaxRequestSample.aspx/GetSum",
      data: requestParameters,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: DisplayResponse,//Event that'll be fired on Success
      error: DisplayError //Event that'll be fired on Error
    });
  }
  function DisplayResponse(serverResponse) {            
    alert('Server Response: Sum of numbers is = '+serverResponse.d);
  }
  function DisplayError(serverResponse) {
    alert("Some Error Occured");
  }

</script>

</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtParameter1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtParameter2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="btnSendJqueryCall" onclick="InitiateJqueryAjaxRequestCall();" type="button"
        value="Invoke Page Method using JQuery" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static int GetSum(int reqParameter1, int reqParameter2)
    {
        return reqParameter1 + reqParameter2;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you press F12 in IE, you can debug the browser-side Javascript.

Comment: Does your GetSum function get called on the server side or it gets terminated even before it ?

Comment: It's getting terminated @   var reqParameter1 = $('#<%= txtParameter1.ClientID %>')[0].value;

Comment: shouldn't is just be `$('#<%= txtParameter1.ClientID %>').value` ?

Comment: @Bala Tried $('#<%= txtParameter1.ClientID %>').value .... No Use :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "terminated"?  Is there an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that jQuery is being successfully loaded?

Comment: I tried your code ,I don't see any problem

Comment: @geek did you do anything extra to make it run? Do i need to change any browser options?

Comment: @NewBie this has nothing to do with "browser options."  I ask again: are you **100% sure** that jQuery is being successfully loaded?  Also, what do you mean by "terminated"?

Comment: @Pointy I put break points to check that and found that the method  InitiateJqueryAjaxRequestCall() is getting called and after crossing the first line within that method, the script is neither showing the success or error message.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the JavaScript console?  What browser are you using?

Comment: @NewBie:No change.I am using IE8 and Mozilla latest version

Comment: @Pointy I'm using Mozilla 3.0.19 with firebug installed.

Comment: If you make the first statement of the function be, `var x = $();` then does that also fail?  (Your characterization of what's happening as the function "terminating" without any error reported still makes no sense at all.)

Comment: Also, that's a really old version of Firefox.

Comment: Don't create JSON on your own, you are misquoting the property names. Use `JSON.stringify({reqParameter1: reqParameter1, reqParameter2: reqParameter2})`

Answer (score 0):

If you send your parameters like this, it works:

```
var requestParameters = '{ reqParameter1:1, reqParameter2:2 }';
```

So, you aren't creating the parameters correctly.